# Ruby Passenger Root:Root User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I have the following problem with passenger

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen
```

I have only root user in server and install all with root user.

Config Passenger

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name localhost;

 passenger_enabled on;
 passenger_app_env testing;
 passenger_user root;
 passenger_group root;
 root /opt/my_app/public;
 error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
  root   html;
 }
}
```

Passenger Version 5.1.8

Thanks for your time!!

xD

Comment: Your error message is too brief. Please post more details, otherwise people can't troubleshoot your problem.